# how to render different items using ngFor based on a condition angular2

Tags: angular, ngfor

i have to dynamically create some html component using ngFor. Need to render different items like textbox,select,etc based on the values form a json.

i know how to do this in javascript using for loop and if condition. but what is the alternate in angular 2 ?

for example

```
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    if(data.type=="textbox"){
      $('#container').append(//textbox snippet)
    }

    if(data.type=="select"){
      $('#container').append(//select snippet)
    }
}
```

what is the alternative for this in angular 2 ? any help much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `*ngFor`? Did you run into any issues?

Comment: if i use ngFor i can repeat only one set of html snippet right ? how to render different snippet based on a condition ?

Comment: Use nested `*ngIf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `*ngIf` directive.

For example :

```
<div *ngIf="(data.type == 'textbox')">
<!--textbox snippet here-->
</div>
```

or

```
<input *ngIf="(data.type == 'textbox')" type="text" value="" />
```

Here is a [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html) about `*ngIf` directive

Comment: @rahulcp does it answer your question? I would really appreciate it if you could mark this as an answer.